# Pulling MySQL Data For Check Boxes And Radio Buttons?

Tags: php, database, checkbox

i have the following data being pulled out from a databasse that is being inserted via checkboxes.

here is the print_r($sockets):

```
a:6:{i:0;s:6:"UK 15A";i:1;s:5:"CEE22";i:2;s:6:"Schuko";i:3;s:6:"French";i:4;s:5:"Swiss";i:5;s:6:"Danish";}
```

What is the best way just to show the checkbox value i.s the ones in-between quotes???

I tried to use explode(); but im not sure if this is right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like serialized data.

you can use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on it

```
$data=unserialize($str);
print_r($data);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => UK 15A
    [1] => CEE22
    [2] => Schuko
    [3] => French
    [4] => Swiss
    [5] => Danish
)
```

Loop through the array and access the values.

Answer (score 0):

it is seralized array

you can use it like this

$sockets = unsiralize($sockets);

echo $sockets[0]; // UK 15A

echo $sockets[4]; // Swiss